# Extension for Google Earth that allows freehand and draggable selection of placemarks

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I have spent about 3 whole days searching for a Google Earth API extension that would enable users to perform selections of placemarks by either clicking multiple points, OR by drawing a polygon. I didn't budget or spec this functionality because I was confident that this is the type of thing that would be readily available for Google Earth. Turns out I was wrong.

At any rate, I am not asking anyone to write the code, I am hoping someone has come across a javascript library that enables this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered GE plugin does not support drawing or dragging without writing some code yourself.

There is an extension library that I have found useful for draggable placemarks.  Use makeDraggable().

Example here:
http://earth-api-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extensions/examples/draggable.html

Source here:
https://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/source/browse/trunk/extensions/src/edit/dragging.js

Comment: Thanks man. I ended up using this library. It's pretty useful. I just found that the documentation is useless unless you have insane levels of knowledge about KML and the Earth API. But that's not your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to look at the second example: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/events#examples

Comment: It's definitely useful